# std::bitset::all substitute for prior C++11 compilers

Tags: c++, c++03, std-bitset

I would like to use the `std::bitset::all` but unfortunately my compiler is pre-dated C++11. I know that I could mimicate the functionality by checking in a loop whether all bits of my `std::bitset` are set.

e.g.,

```
template<std::size_t N>
bool
all(std::bitset<N> const &bs) {
  int hits(0), sz(bs.size());
  for(int i(0); i < sz; ++i) {
    hits += bs[i];
  }
  return hits == sz;
}
```

### Q:

Is there a more proper implementation of a `std::bitset::all` substitute for pre-dated C++11 compilers than the one displayed above.

Comment: How about `bs == -1`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant if `N` is bigger than the number of bits in an `unsigned long long` that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Just check if the [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count) is equal to [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/size):

```
template<size_t N>
bool all_set(const std::bitset<N>& b) {
    return b.count() == b.size();
}
```

Comment: This turns out not to be the case. 
!none() === any()

Comment: I've fixed it. Sorry, been too tired.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet is that PHP's `operator===` you're trying to sneak into C++?

Comment: Do not speak that name here :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid a loop, but don't care about maximum performace, you could compare `count` against `size` (i.e. check if the number of bits set equals the number of bits):

```
template<std::size_t N>
bool all(std::bitset<N> const &bs) {
    return bs.count() == bs.size();
}
```

The downside (but that's the same with other non-loop solutions as well as your implementation with a loop) is that it won't stop early at the first bit not being set. If you'd like to take advantage of that, modify your loop to exit early (and by the way, you don't need `sz` as it is `N`):

```
template<std::size_t N>
bool all(std::bitset<N> const &bs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (!bs[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since `size()` is O(1) and both `all()` and `count()` are O(n), I'd say your original solution is in the same big-Oh class as `all()`

Comment: @Bulletmagnet Of course both are linear in N, that's the big-Oh. But if you care about maximum performance (which I usually don't, but looking at a lot of Stack Overflow questions most people seem to do), you shouldn't only look at big-Oh but also at constant factors or special cases. And if you exit early, you optimize for cases which have non-set bits near the beginning. It might be slower though, since it introduces a conditional branch (which is easily predictable to be fair). You can discuss a lot here but that's all premature optimization which I consider bad. I just gave an alternative.

Comment: Note also that most of bitset's O(n) methods (`count()`, `all()`, `none()`, `any()` ...) work on `unsigned long`s at a time. This means that `count() == `size()` might actually be faster than calling `operator[]` in a loop.

Comment: Another downside to the early-exit one is that it becomes nearly impossible to vectorize.  A well written `count` could add up 128 bits or more at a time.

Comment: @Yakk I know, that's why I said "optimize for cases which have non-set bits near the beginning". You make the worst case much worse. But I'd like to emphasize again: that's all premature optimization, and I'm an enemy of that. I write concise code, and optimize only when I identified a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

A silly way would be

```
(~bs).none();
```

(silly because `operator~` returns a temporary).

Comment: Silly because it does unnecessary work: it creates another bitset object, calls a method on it, then throws the new object away. I believe it's a premature pessimization :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `bs.count() == bs.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use template metaprogramming and unroll the bits of the bitfield like the example below:

```
template<std::size_t N, int M>
struct bitset_all_helper {
  static bool check(std::bitset<N> const &bs) { return bs[M] && bitset_all_helper<N, M - 1>::check(bs); }
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct bitset_all_helper<N, 0> {
  static bool check(std::bitset<N> const &bs) { return bs[0]; }
};

template<std::size_t N>
bool bitset_all(std::bitset<N> const &bs) { return bitset_all_helper<N, N - 1>::check(bs); }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab12632f5d0b994c)

Comment: That's almost the same than simply writing a usual for-loop. The compiler is smart enough to unroll it for you, no ugly meta-programming required (not that I dislike meta-programming, but here it is simply not necessary).

Comment: In my experience, compilers are pretty conservative in unrolling. This solution almost forces the compiler to unroll (it actually "asks" it to inline, which I guess no compiler would refuse).